# Using JOINS in UPDATE statement when merging in SQLite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I'm currently working with distributed SQLite Databases.
Each client has it's own database which he can sync with the server database.

The server receives a database from a client and updates and inserts it's own rows according to the database the client sends.

While inserting new records is as easy as:

```
ATTACH DATABASE 'clients_uploaded_db' AS toMerge;
INSERT INTO `presentation` SELECT * FROM toMerge.presentation WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT id FROM `presentation`
)
```

updating is not. I need to check if a client record has changed (`presentation.changedate` has a smaller value than `presentation.changedate` in the client db) and update if necessary.

In DBMS such as MySQL the following would be possible. But using joins on UPDATEs in SQLite is not possible.

```
ATTACH DATABASE 'clients_uploaded_db' AS toMerge;
UPDATE presentation 
INNER JOIN toMerge.presentation AS tp ON
   id = tp.id 
SET
    label = tp.label
WHERE 
    tp.changedate > changedate
```

I've read through several SO questions but I could only find solutions where only one row needs to be updated or where the id's are known.

---

**DB-Structure**

**server_db:**

presentation (*id:pk, label, changedate*)

**clients_uploaded_db:**

presentation (*id:pk, label, changedate*)

---

**TL;DR**

I can't join tables on UPDATE but I need to make rows of a table exactly the same as the rows on a table on another database that is made available in my query, but only when the `changedate` col of the second database is higher than that of the first one.

---

**What I have done so far**

- Tried to join the regarding tables
- Iterated programatically through the records and updated if necessary (works fine but is a performance killer)

Answer (score 1):

SQLite doesn't support a `from` clause.  So you have to do this with correlated subqueries.  It is not clear what your update is supposed to be doing.  But here is an example

```
UPDATE presentation 
SET label = (select tp.label
             from toMerge.presentation tp
             where presentation.id = tp.id and
                   tp.changedate > presentation.changedate
             order by tp.change_date
             limit 1);
```

Comment: Thanks :) I'll give it a try. My update is supposed to reflect the changes of the `toMerge` database if something has changed.